# join table on itself, only join at most n rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

im really new to sql, so i may be missing something obivous!

i have a table of nfl game stats and im joining it on itself so that i can get a players game stats, and their stats from a previous game. obviously as the season progresses there are more previous games. is there a way i can get at most 3 games back?

| Name | Game Date | Receiving Yards | Receiving TDs | Previous Game Date | Previous Receiving Yards | Previous Receiving TDs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Davante Adams | 2020-12-27 | 142 | 3 | 2020-12-19 | 42 | 0 |
| Davante Adams | 2020-12-27 | 142 | 3 | 2020-12-13 | 115 | 1 |
| Davante Adams | 2020-12-27 | 142 | 3 | 2020-12-06 | 121 | 2 |

my goal is to have only these 3 rows for adams 2020-12-27 the way the self join i have now works it will just have a row for every game of adams career before 2020-12-27 (119 games) as the previous stats

this is the join i have now:

```
FROM nfl_historic_games g
JOIN nfl_historic_games p ON p.playerid = g.playerid 
AND p.game_date::text < g.game_date::text
```

Comment: I don't understand why a self-join would be needed for previous game stats.  I think your question needs more elaboration.

Comment: @GordonLinoff im joining the stats table on itself like this:

 FROM nfl_historic_games g JOIN nfl_historic_games p ON p.playername = g.playername AND p.game_date < g.game_date 

basically finding rows with the same player and earlier date, again its possible im going about this in a bad way lol

Comment: Rather than this, Just post your sample data from your table and post the expected output from that data.

Comment: i updated my main post with some sample data!

Comment: Your sample data doesn't look right.  GameDate for each of those records should be different shouldn't it?

Comment: no the first row is 1 game back for 2020-12-27, the second row is 2 games back and the third is 3 games back! my issue is that i want it to stop there but my join will get a row for 4 games back, 5 games back, and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you an idea of what to mess around with. It's not tested but the gist is hopefully clear.
How exactly it behaves, like null handling during the first three games (since you don't have 3 previous) or bye weeks will just depend on how you want to do it.

```
WITH RANKED_GAMES AS
  ( SELECT G.*,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
             ( PARTITION BY G.playerID
                   ORDER BY G.GameDate DESC
             ) game_rank
      FROM nfl_historic_games 
  )
SELECT RG1.GameDate,
       RG1.PlayerID,
       RG1.Receiving_Yard,
       RG1.Receiving_TDS,
       PREV_RG.GameDate AS Previous_GameDate,
       PREV_RG.Receiving_Yard AS Previous_Receiving_Yards
  FROM RANKED_GAMES RG1
 INNER
  JOIN RANKED_GAMES PREV_RG
    ON RG1.playerID = PREV_RG.playerID
   AND PREV_RG.game_rank BETWEEN RG1.game_rank + 1 AND RG1.game_rank + 3
```

Comment: wow! this is exactly what i was looking for thanks :D